# How to you API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get from API the data and don't know how.

So I am trying to use this API https://api.abalin.net/get/today?country=cz and don't know really how.

```
<div id="data"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("https://api.abalin.net/get/today?country=cz", function(data){




            $("#data").append(data.results[0].name_cz );
        }           
    )
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain ?

Comment: @AndreaManzi not relevant here since the api is cors enabled and is not serving JSONP

Answer (score 2):

The response is an object that has  property `data` and not `results`.

[`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is also a better ajax shortcut method for making json GET requests.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.abalin.net/get/today?country=cz", function(res) {
  console.log('name_cz = ', res.data.name_cz);
  console.log('month = ', res.data.month);
  
  $('#data').text(res.data.name_cz);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```